# Put text over image without 'position: absolute;' and wrap it to fit compartment in CSS grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position, css-grid

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(18vw, 1fr) );
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(35vh, 1fr);
  gap: 20px 20px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity:0.85;
  background: green;
  color: #efefef;
  font-size:2em;
  border-radius:10px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.box img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}

.box p  {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: calc(0.9em + 0.9vw);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <a href='link' class="box">
    <img src="src/img.png"/>
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </a>
  <a href='link2' class="box">
    <img src="src/img2.png"/>
    <p>ANOTHER TEXT</p>
  </a>
  ...
</div>
```

Everything works fine, the image is centered horizontally and vertically in its 'box' and the text is also centered (v&h) and over the image. Everything is responsive to window size so the wider the more boxes per column and the text gets bigger.

The only problem is that the text does not break into lines and overflows its box with some windows sizes. Is there a way of making the text in the `<p>` element to break in lines according to the size of the box?

[image]

I have multiple variations like using word-wrap (overflow-wrap), putting the `<img>` and the `<p>` inside another `<div>` and ... but nothing seems to work.

========================

Edit based on comments.

The `position: absolute;` of the `.box p` elements is moving its content out of the flow. Maybe a better option would be to get the effect of text over image by another method. Any idea about how to do it?

Edited title to describe better the question after comments

Comment: Try :-      .box p  { word-break: break-all; }

Comment: Thanks for the comment @S.M but adding that has no effect.

Comment: Really hard to visualize in your snippet with the text color `#efefef` and no border on the box.

Comment: `position: absolute` on the `.box p` pulls that content out of the flow, which is why it doesn't wrap ... it's not "in" the container so the boundaries don't affect it. If you get rid of that the text wraps, then you'd have to find some other way to position it where you want.

Comment: Hi @StephenP, I had the same intuition but wanted to ask to see if someone had an idea about how to do it. I have just realized I forgot the background of the box in my copy/paste.

Comment: `.box { position: relative; }` will help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with `position: absolute` , use `position: relative;` on the parent container to make the child element use the parent as it's positional reference ([position: relative and position: absolute summary here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values)). Also, added `.box p  { text-align: center }`

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(18vw, 1fr) );
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(35vh, 1fr);
  gap: 20px 20px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity:0.85;
  background: green;
  color: #efefef;
  font-size:2em;
  border-radius:10px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.box img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}

.box p  {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: calc(12px);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <a href='link' class="box">
    <img src="src/img.png"/>
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </a>
  <a href='link2' class="box">
    <img src="src/img2.png"/>
    <p>ANOTHER TEXT that is much longer to show that you can center the text.</p>
  </a>
  ...
</div>
```